# Ionic - Update splash screen doesn't work

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app with version `3.12.0` and I'm trying to update the app icon and splash.

I put `icon.png` and `splash.png` in `resources` folder and run:

```
ionic cordova resources --icon
ionic cordova resources --splash
```

And it just update the icon and not the splash. In splash shows the old.

After that I `remove the android and ios folder` from resources and run:

```
ionic cordova resources
```

It create well all both folders again with correct icon but with old splash. How can I solve this?

In all commands that I run show me this warning and I don't know if it can be the reason for that, I think not because the icon was well generated and updated.

```
[WARN] Error with ./www/lib/ionic/version.json file: FILE_NOT_FOUND, trying
   ./bower.json.
```

Thank you

Comment: does your `splash.png` image followed the guideline https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/resources/

Comment: Yes. the splash.png has 2732 × 4858 I put it in resources/ and I also try to put inside resources/ios and resources/android but it put . always the old splash.  @Saikat1529

Comment: try to use `sudo ionic cordova resources --force` and check if it works.

Comment: Doesn't work. It's the same! @Saikat1529

Comment: try `ionic cordova resources --splash --verbose` and see if you get any logs

Comment: I try this first tell that doesn't exist changes, after that I remove splash folder in both platforms and run this command. Generate the images but continue putting the old splash. @SurajRao

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
$npm rebuild node-sass --force
```

after generating splash and icon.

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).

Answer (score 1):

from https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/

"App on target may not reflect changes to images Once you run the app on a target, iOS caches the launch image. Unfortunately, when you change the image, iOS does not invalidate the cache, which means you'll still see the old launch image. You should either: delete the app, or reset content & settings (simulator)."

Comment: in my case, changing  widget id and version in config.xml file solved that problem...